# Youtube Flash API stalls when playing

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-api

I have a YouTube player written in ActionScript 3. Recently it's been crashing when playing videos, not at the same point but generally around 1/4 of the way in.

I'm echoing the player state and any event changes to console which is listing it as state 1 while it's playing (this is expected behaviour) but then when it crashes it changes to '3' which is "buffering". From here however it never plays again and from what I can tell from my network window (Chrome developer tools) it's not loading any new information

```
    Play Time: 83.421
    Player state: 1
    Player Loaded fraction: 0.48829904193497725

    Play Time: 83.922
    Player state: 1
    Player Loaded fraction: 0.48829904193497725

State Change: 3

    Play Time: 84.166
    Player state: 3
    Player Loaded fraction: 0.48829904193497725

    Play Time: 84.166
    Player state: 3
    Player Loaded fraction: 0.48829904193497725
```

The Loaded fraction refers to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#getVideoLoadedFraction) which seems to stop incrementing at around 75 seconds in the above case.

Our code is pretty much the example code [from here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Loading) with a few `ExternalInterface.call('console.log', foo)` lines here and there.

**First question:**

Is this a common issue? I can't see much else about videos changing to a "buffering" state and not recovering. Do I need to run anything to resume play?

**Second question:**

If this is a bigger problem than just flash (network issues etc), what would be the best way to tell the client. I was thinking of checking if it was in a buffering state for more than X seconds and then displaying a message. Any better ideas?

---

**Edit**:

I've been trying to pinpoint the exact cause and try to find patterns in what happens. I've noticed this morning that (with the video I am testing) the stalls always happened around 0.25. If it hadn't stalled by then, the whole video will play through fine.

[image: Stall Table]

The more I take down details, the more I see re-occurrences in the ratio, with a number that long, it can't be a random disconnect.

Comment: Please use https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report) for reporting bugs related to the YouTube API, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Jeff, When I first posted here, I assumed it was on my end, (it may still be) Before I post a bug report I'll finish my testing, does this look like anything you've seen before?